# PySpark Pipeline - Logistic Regression results too good to be true

Tags: python, pyspark, logistic-regression

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to predict if a review is positive or negative while using a simple PySpark ML Pipeline. Everything seems to work, however, I think something is wrong and I'm simply overlooking it. I'm getting an accuracy score of 0.9997, while other people obtain results of 0.90 on this dataset (from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/imdb-movie-reviews-dataset)).

The input data consists out of a DF with a column 'review', containing a string with the review and a column 'label', containing the label.

I'm setting up my pipeline as following:

```
# Configure pipeline stages 
tok = Tokenizer(inputCol="review", outputCol="words") 
htf = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="tf", numFeatures=200) 
idf = IDF(inputCol="tf", outputCol="idf")
va = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["tf","idf", "label"], outputCol="features") 
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01).setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("features")

# Build the pipeline
stages=[tok, htf, idf, va,lr]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages) 
# Fit the pipeline 
pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(train)
# Make predictions
df_results = pipeline_model.transform(train)
df_results = df_results.select('review','label','prediction')
test_results = pipeline_model.transform(test)
test_results = test_results.select('review','label','prediction')
```

Why is thig happening? I'm telling the lr what the label column and feature column are...

Comment: Can you tell me why you are " pipeline.fit(train) " but also " pipeline_model.transform(train) " ? Isn't it that you should transform your test data? Am new so this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your features contain the label

`va = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["tf","idf", "label"], outputCol="features")`

So your LR is getting the desired output as an input :) Just remove it from features:

```
va = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["tf","idf"], outputCol="features")
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, I noticed it as well. Thanks a lot!